# Facebook Graph API: Get the work history of a friend

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get a work information of my friends.

It's possible to get this with Graph API v2?

Comment: before creating new questions, you should take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour - you should also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can only get data of friends who authorized your App.** They also have to authorize your App with the `user_work_history` permission. After that, you can get it with the following API call:

```
/me/friends?fields=name,work
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. ;)